# Data Scraping on Cross-Platform process UiPath

Tags: cross-platform, uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-activity

I created a **process** in UiPath Studio on a Windows machine which scrapes data from a website, below are the components used for creating the process[image: Process created in UiPath Studio]

How to replicate the same on a cross-platform machine(Linux)

As we know, for Windows we have UiPath Studio that can use the DataScraping tool which opens the browser and we select things and give patterns for moving forward. But can we replicate the same functionality in Cross-platform Process with limited packages that support cross-platform in UiPath?
If yes, how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

UiPath is **NOT** natively running on Linux. You will need to set up a docker to run UiPath.

On [Linux Robots](https://docs.uipath.com/robot/docs/linux-robots) you get all the points.

But as you want to use UI element interaction, you need the Chrome. So better have a look on [**Chrome Automation on Linux**](https://docs.uipath.com/activities/docs/chrome-automation-on-linux-robots) how to do.